# Set default value when textfield is empty swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm wondering if there's a way to set a custom value to a UITextField that is empty.

**CONTEXT** : I have to let users set their own schedule for the whole month day by day and if an user doesn't have anything on a certain day, then he won't have to write in the corresponding day field and it should display a "x" in that day of his schedule.

I'm working with firebase to save the days value.

Here's a snippet of my code :

```
@objc func SaveSchedule() {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Schedule")


        let values = ["dim1": self.edtDim1.text ?? "x",
                      "lun1": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mar1": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mer1": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "jeu1": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "ven1": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "sam1": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "dim2": self.edtDim1.text!,
                      "lun2": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mar2": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mer2": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "jeu2": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "ven2": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "sam2": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "dim3": self.edtDim1.text!,
                      "lun3": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mar3": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mer3": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "jeu3": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "ven3": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "sam3": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "dim4": self.edtDim1.text!,
                      "lun4": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mar4": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "mer4": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "jeu4": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "ven4": self.edtLun1.text!,
                      "sam4": self.edtLun1.text!] as [NSString : Any]
        ref.setValue(values)
    }
```

As you can see, I've tried "dim1" ?? to put a "x" if empty.. Doesn't work. By the way, my days are prefixes of french days.

**MY QUESTION** : How can I, if there's no value set for the text field, set a default "x" in my firebase? I'd prefer a simple "one line code" if possible.

Thanks in advance,
Have a good day/evening/night

Comment: this command `??` work if value is nil  , you can use this
 `self.edtDim1.text!.isEmpty ? "x" : self.edtDim1.text! `

Comment: Thanks for your answer @a.masri , I'm trying that right away!

Comment: Please define *"Doesn't work"* ...

Comment: Sets the value "" <---(empty string) in my firebase.

Answer (score 0):

A textfield has a default value of empty string ""  , So you can try

```
extension UITextfield
{
  var:currentValue:String {
      return self.text != "" ? self.text : "x"
  }

}
```

then use

```
nameTexf.currentValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    @objc func SaveSchedule() {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Schedule")

    let dimValue = self.edtDim1.text! == "" ? "x" : self.edtDim1.text!

    let lunValue = self.edtLun1.text! == "" ? "" : self.edtLun1.text!

    let values = ["dim1": dimValue,
                  "lun1": lunValue,
                  "mar1": lunValue,
                  "mer1": lunValue,
                  "jeu1": lunValue,
                  "ven1": lunValue,
                  "sam1": lunValue,
                  "dim2": dimValue,
                  "lun2": lunValue,
                  "mar2": lunValue,
                  "mer2": lunValue,
                  "jeu2": lunValue,
                  "ven2": lunValue,
                  "sam2": lunValue,
                  "dim3": dimValue,
                  "lun3": lunValue,
                  "mar3": lunValue,
                  "mer3": lunValue,
                  "jeu3": lunValue,
                  "ven3": lunValue,
                  "sam3": lunValue,
                  "dim4": dimValue,
                  "lun4": lunValue,
                  "mar4": lunValue,
                  "mer4": lunValue,
                  "jeu4": lunValue,
                  "ven4": lunValue,
                  "sam4": lunValue] as [NSString : Any]

    ref.setValue(values)
}
```

this will fill your value array like this:

```
[sam2: "", mar3: "", dim4: "x", ven2: "", mer3: "", sam1: "", lun3: "", lun1: "", mer2: "", jeu3: "", lun4: "", dim1: "x", sam4: "", ven1: "", mer4: "", lun2: "", jeu4: "", dim3: "x", ven3: "", sam3: "", mar2: "", mar4: "", mer1: "", jeu1: "", jeu2: "", ven4: "", mar1: "", dim2: "x"]
```

you can also set the default value for "edtLun1"